# Missing module error when installing lmdb (windows)

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install wikipedia2vec on windows.
I am running "pip install wikipedia2vec"

It throws an error: Building py-lmdb from source on Windows requires the "patch-ng" python module while collecting lmdb (Full stack trace below)

I have already ran "pip install patch-ng" and that project installed successfully.

I dug around the web and found a suggestion to install VS Build Tools. Done that and it did not help (that seemed like a long shot).

I am out of ideas as to what might be causing it...

Here's the full stack trace:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3.12 but the stable release of `wikipedia2vec` currently supports lower versions of Python namely 2.7, 3.3 - 3.6 see [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia2vec/).

To resolve this, downgrade your python version to perhaps 3.6. **Do not remove
your installation of Python 3.12**. You can use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to manage this.