# pip won't install requirements.txt because I'm missing a dependency, even though I already installed the dependency

Tags: python, pip

I used `pip install -r requirements.txt`, which I think is supposed to automatically install dependencies. I got `Exception: Building py-lmdb from source on Windows requires the "patch-ng" python module.`. Running `pip install patch-ng` just says `Requirement already satisfied: patch-ng in c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (1.17.4)`. In short, I can't use patch-ng because it's not installed, but I can't install it because it's already installed. I even tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it and this did not fix the issue.

I was worried that it may have somehow been doing that with different versions of Python. So I ran `py -0p` to see all versions installed, deleted all but the newest one, and then ran `py -0p` again, verifying that my computer is now haunted by previous python installations, which are still installed despite being in folders that no longer exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77763387/missing-module-error-when-installing-lmdb-windows

Comment: That was helpful. I'm switching to the correct version of Python. The only problem is that pip is no longer installed, but I can't install it because it's already installed. And I checked the PATH to make sure it's correct.

Edit: Looks like it works if I call it pip3.